# Reading an io.Reader of unknown size into bytes array in golang

Tags: go

I have a file (say the descriptor is named `file`) opened via the `os.Open()` method so I want to read its contents into a bytes array.

I assume the approach would be to create the later

```
data := make([]byte, 10000000)
```

and then read the contents into it

```
n, err := file.Read(data)
```

My question is whether there is a more elegant/go-idiomatic way of going about this since by not knowing in advance the file size, I just pass a number I estimate would do (`10000000`) upon initialisation of the bytes array.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadAll. Read doesn't work anyway because the underlaying reader isn't obligated to return all data in one go.

Comment: I think that's the correct answer; if you post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `io/ioutil` (up to Go 1.15) or `os` (Go 1.16 and higher) package. There is a helper function that reads an entire file into a byte slice.

```
// For Go 1.15 and lower:
package main

import "io/ioutil"

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("path/to/my/file")
}
```

```
// For Go 1.16 and higher:
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    data, err := os.ReadFile("path/to/my/file")
}
```

In Go version 1.16 the `io/ioutil` function is still there for compatibility reasons but it was replicated in `os`. I assume that it will stay in `io/ioutil` for as long as Go has a version 1.xx because of the compatibility promise so you might keep using that one.

In case you have a file descriptor or any `io.Reader` you can use the `io/ioutil` package as well:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Open("path/to/my/file")
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ioutil.ReadAll()` is a wrapper for `io.ReadAll()` and it use predetermined size "512" bytes which [enlarge](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.6:src/io/io.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.6;l=631) as the read loops.

You can instead use the size from `(*file.File).Stats().Size()`.

A more straightforward method would be using `os.ReadFile()` which automatically *convert* a file into []byte for you. It creates []byte with sizes from `Stats().Size()` method [above](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.6:src/os/file.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.6;l=677) before reading the file into byte.